# Ubuntu sys/byteorder.h & sys/endian.h missing, while building MySQL Connector/C++

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

Bear in mind that I'm a beginner when it comes to building from source (tried a few times, almost always failed).

I'm trying to build the MySQL Connector/C++ 8 for my Raspberry Pi 3b running Ubuntu 19. I followed the [offical instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-prerequisites.html) and have all prerequisites installed (not 100% sure if `codecvt_utf8` is present).

I'm building without JDBC and BOOST. I've build OpenSSL 1.1.1 from source.

The commands I'm running (i've added `--target install` directly - not sure if that's an issue):

```bsh
cmake .
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
```

It fails AFAIK, due to this:

> CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
>
> CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/byteorder.h: No such file or directory

I've checked `/usr/include` and there is no directory `sys`. The `endian.h` is directly at the top-level and `byteorder.h` is not present at all.

Why are some files missing?

---

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414110/wheres-my-usr-include-sys-directory), the `sys` directory is in a different location on Ubuntu. So I ran this:

```bsh
ln -s /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/sys /usr/include/sys
```

But the missing files are not actually in that directory either.

---

Running

```bsh
find /usr/include -type f -name endian.h
find /usr/include -type f -name byteorder.h
```

reveals, that the files are actually in `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/endian.h` and `/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/asm/byteorder.h`, should I just link those? Seems like a bad idea.

---

Full output (using cached progress):

```
[  2%] Built target uuid_gen
[  4%] Building protobuf
[ 27%] Built target protobuf-lite
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/protobuf-3.6.1/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc.o
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/build.make:115: CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/protobuf-3.6.1/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:73: CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [cdk/CMakeFiles/build_protobuf.dir/build.make:58: cdk/protobuf/build.stamp] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:297: cdk/CMakeFiles/build_protobuf.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Full error log:

```
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test HAVE_IS_SAME failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_dadf7/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -DHAVE_IS_SAME  -std=c++11   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/src.cxx.o -c /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:1: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      | ^~~~
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:22: error: ‘is_same’ was not declared in this scope
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      |                      ^~~~~~~
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:30: error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      |                              ^~~~
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:30: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘bool’
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      |                              ^~~~
      |                              ;
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:34: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘,’ token
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      |                                  ^
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1:35: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘char’
    1 | void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
      |                                   ^~~~
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_dadf7.dir/src.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_dadf7/fast] Error 2

Source file was:
void main() { return is_same<bool,char>::value; }
Determining if the include file sys/endian.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_a570b/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <sys/endian.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_a570b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_a570b/fast] Error 2


Determining if the include file sys/byteorder.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_e560b/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/byteorder.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <sys/byteorder.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_e560b.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/mysql-connector-c++-8.0.18-src/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_e560b/fast] Error 2
```

---

cmake 3.13.4
g++ 9.2.1
openssl 1.1.1d

Comment: Can you try building it in a separate directory without using cmake to actually build it? Assuming you are in the same directory (alongside the CMakeLists.txt) as the previous commands you ran, something like `mkdir build && cd build`, `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, and then `make`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7725055 and https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#out-of-source-build-trees for more information.

Comment: @Joe I will try, but don't think it will effect the missing file issue.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the kernel headers, which I believe can be installed with the linux-headers-generic package  on Ubuntu. The kernel headers ship with the kernel rather than the C library because they're architecture specific.

Comment: @MatthewGauthier Thanks for the hint, I installed the package but the `sys` directory is still missing and it still fails for the same reason.

Comment: `sys/endian.h` (and I expect `sys/byteorder.h` too) sound like BSD-only header files. `CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c` sounds like CMake checking for their presence (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFile.html more info) - if they don't exist, it adjusts the build as appropriate. Assuming the error identified in the question is not the actual error, is there anything else in the logs?

Comment: @Joe Thanks, didn't know that. The error is only followed up with (shortend):`compilation terminated.`, `.../CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1`, `leaving directory`, `make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_e560b/fast] Error 2`. That's it, I really have no idea how to read / interpret these files properly.

Comment: What does the `cmake .. . . .` command output? (e.g. `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`)

Comment: @Joe I'm going to run it again (it's going to take a few minutes) and edit my question.

Comment: Sounds like gcc is running out of memory during compilation (to check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35011967) - try building with one thread. If this is already the case, then try cross-compiling for the Pi on another machine with more memory using a toolchain built for such a purpose - see https://blog.kitware.com/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi/ for an example, including how to integrate the toolchain with CMake (ideal for this situation). It might also help to change the GPU/CPU memory split and, if not already, disabling graphical login, to try and increase the amount of available memory.

Comment: For the memory split and graphical login options, see `raspi-config`.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the hint, it is a memory issue. I'll try one thread then, how do I specify `-j1` for cmake?

Comment: `-j1` is a parameter you can pass to `make`, so after your build directory is set up (e.g. via `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`), you can run `make -j1`. There might be a way to pass it in via the commands listed above (`cmake --build . --target install --config Release`), however I'm unfamiliar with directly using cmake to build. Instead, I would advise creating a build directory, running `cmake <path to the source code> -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`, followed by `make -j1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the C++ compiler is running out of memory. Try specifying 1 thread when building with make, for example:

```bsh
$ cd path/to/connector/source
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ make -j1
```

(this is known as an ["out-of-source"](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#out-of-source-build-trees) build)

If that fails, and the Pi still does not have enough memory, use the `raspi-config` tool (run as root) to adjust the Pi's memory split, giving as little as possible to the GPU, and disable graphical login, to try and increase the amount of free memory for compiling. Then, reboot so that the changes take effect, and then build as you would from the console. If all goes well, you can then use `raspi-config` again to adjust the previously modified settings back to their original values. If that fails, then you might want to consider cross-compiling on another Linux machine with more memory. A guide on how to build a cross-compilation toolchain for the Pi using `crosstool-ng`, and then build a CMake project using it, can be found here: https://blog.kitware.com/cross-compiling-for-raspberry-pi/.

Comment: It's working now. I am running in CLI, so I couldn't save memory from graphics, but mysql took ~50% of my memory, so I saved memory there: `service mysql stop`.